# SearchView for a List of Data

Tags: android, searchview

I have a list of data, and I want that my app search in this only 50 entries.
I follow [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html) from google, I have now Search Button in my app. 
I followed many other tutorials to implement my searchView, but no one was sufficient. Therefore, can any one of you give me an example or any tutorial, that helps me to implement this SearchView?

Comment: your app need to search data from Google or from webservice

Comment: They are my data, they are only 50 entries, I want to search during this 50 entries, and when the user clicks on the entry, an activity will be called.
Which way is the best way to make that? Can I use ListView instead?